# Symfony - Route 404

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony (4.1) project. In this project i need to create new route, like this.

Controller

```
 /**
 *
 * @Route("/search-user", name="search-user")
 */
 public function searchUser(Request $request)
 {
      dd("Search user");
      return $this->render("XXX");
 }
```

Routes.yaml

```
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix: '/'
```

The problem: When i go to endpoint/search-user returns 404 not found.

I´m some new in Symfony, so somebody can see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can launch

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

to have a list of all your existing routing.
Can you add your controller declaration?

- check that is in the src/Controller folder
- check that there is no routing prefix in your controller (@route before class declaration)